# Perforce CLI reconcile adds 'ghost' files to my working directory

Tags: command-line, perforce

Have a perplexing bug when I try to reconcile work through the CLI for perforce in that I get a large amount of files detected and added to the changelist whenever I run the command.

This happens regardless of where my current working directory is but the files always come from there, if my working directory is outside the project's root I get a 'Path {path} is not under client's root' error and they are not added, however if my working directory is under the project root they are detected and added as missing files.

I've tried numerous different combinations of the reconcile command, explicitly stating the port, user, client etc., setting up P4Config, using relative and absolute paths, changing the working directory - but I always get these ghost files.

Has anyone come across this before? Could this be a bug with P4 itself?

Edit: I finally fixed this by reinstalling P4V so I'm assuming this was some bug either my install of perforce or any local config files that would have been reset upon reinstall. For reference this is the page that finally fixed it https://community.perforce.com/s/article/15324

Comment: What are the names of some of these "ghost files"? What happens when you look for them on the local filesystem?

Comment: @Samwise they're all just random numbered files or folders (no extensions so can't tell which they are) seemingly with no order either, and take the form C:/root/workingDir/999#1, where 999 would be the number of the file and #1 the revision.

Nothing appears there in the local file system and no command line list of files brings anything up either (Get-ChildItem etc.)

I've fixed it now by reinstalling P4V so I assume it is a bug with perforce itself.

Comment: I hunted through the relnotes and found the specific bug (job102470), see my answer below.  Reinstalling the same version wouldn't fix it, but you must have been on a buggy version and upgraded to the latest as a side effect of the procedure you went through.

Comment: Ah amazing, good to have some closure on this one cheers! I'll mark your answer as the accepted one since it doesn't rely on blindly updating like mine :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the result of the following bug:

https://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/user/relnotes.txt

```
Bugs fixed in 2020.1 Patch 1 (2020.1/1991450)

    ...

    #1964794 (Job #102470) *
        'p4 reconcile'/'p4 status' might report about invalid filenames
        of the form '//depot/0' or '//depot/100', etc.  This is fixed.
```

Since this was fixed in a 2020.1 patch, it can be inferred that it only affects specific 2020.1 builds (i.e. those before the patch).

To fix it, make sure you're on a client version (p4 or P4V; this is not a server-side bug) whose changelist number is higher than 1964794.  No special reinstallation procedure is needed; just download the latest binary/installer from Perforce's website.

Answer (score 0):

Force a reinstall of P4V to fix this, details can be found here:
https://community.perforce.com/s/article/15324

Or if that page is taken down for any reason:

SOLUTION
Forcing a reinstall using the Windows msiexec installer utility with Windows msi installer file extracted from the p4vinst64.exe file can often successfully complete a full reinstall where running the P4V exe installer such as "p4vinst64.exe" fails

If not already downloaded, obtain the appropiate Windows installer for P4V (for example "p4vinst64.exe" for 64 bit Windows platforms). Currently these can be downloaded from https://www.perforce.com/downloads/helix-visual-client-p4v

Extract the msi from p4vinst64.exe; for example to extract it to  "c:\p4v", open a Windows a cmd prompt and change directory to the location where p4vinst64.exe .is located  and run the following command:

p4vinst64.exe /s /b"c:\p4v" /v"/qn"

Now from c:\p4v, run the following command to force a full reinstall:
msiexec /i "p4vinst64.msi" /qn REINSTALL=ALL REINSTALLMODE=vamus /L*v log.txt